# Change modification time stamp with vbscript

Tags: windows, date, vbscript

i need to change modification time stamp in windows files with vbscrip after copying them.
Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it by setting the FolderItem.ModifyDate property. Everything is described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787825%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
Sample code:

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

Set objFolder = objShell.NameSpace("C:\Scripts")
Set objFolderItem = objFolder.ParseName("File.jpg")

objFolderItem.ModifyDate = "01/01/2008 8:00:00 AM"
```

Comment: Thanks Konrad. Just what i need.

Answer (score -1):

According to the [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8xh895w%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)

> DateLastModified
>
> Property Returns the date and time that the specified
> file or folder was last modified. Read-only.

the property is read-only.

Comment: According to the same docs [ModifyDate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787825%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), @Konrad is right.  Thanks anyway.